# why datepicker in angularjs showing current date

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

```
enter code here :<md-datepicker ng-model="xyz" md-placeholder="trail date"></md-datepicker>
```

I only wrote this much code but it is showing current date. I didn't provide it any value through ng-model still it is showing current date. Initially, I do not want any value.

Comment: Can you show your code? There are many date-pickers so we need to know what you used

Comment: Can you provide the code you have written?

Comment: i am using angular material date-picker

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not provided any code, I am unable to check and see what you are doing. Perhaps using [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) would allow you to set an initial value of nothing?

As per the docs though, its important not to over abuse ng-init and instead apply values in your controller instead.

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, **you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope**.

But at-least ng-init will allow you to do a quick test.